# Several react apps for different part of a web app?

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, netlify

Here is a question on how to structure a web app based on react.
We are planning on deploying the front-end of an app that will contain several parts like main part, a customer account part and say a backoffice part for the company staff to track customer's data etc...

The plan is to deploy this app on Netlify and use subdomains like example.com, backoffice.example.com and clients.example.com.

My question is: shall we use a single React app to handle these 3 parts or use 3 different React apps ?

Initially we thought using 3 different apps would be better in terms of maintenance and evolution but any professional feedback with pros and cons would be appreciated.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar (but with Angular).  It works well as each of the teams is responsible for their own app as far as maintenance and release cycles is concerned. It is pretty scalable as well - no problems to just keep adding new apps (as we are doing).

We have the whole lot behind NGINX, and so in the code we can just refer to simple paths like `/client-services`, `/marketing` and `/sales` - i.e. no server/protocol configurations.

You need to keep the following in mind :

- How the apps interact with each other i.e. a standard data object, or cookies/localStorage
- Authentication
- You will be using app/internal routing for modules within your app, and external routing to redirect to other apps

We've been burnt before with one monolithic app...